# Why immutable.Set.get(x) doesn't work as immutable.List.get(x)?

Tags: immutable.js

I'm starting to use immutable.js and don't understand why get method of Sets doesn't show the same result as the get method from Lists

```
import { fromJS, List, Map, Set } from 'immutable';

const things = fromJS(
  [
    {
      id: 9,
      nome: 'nove'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      nome: 'sete'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      nome: 'oito'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      nome: 'oito'
    }
  ]
).toSet();

const moreThings = fromJS(
  [
    {
      id: 9,
      nome: 'nove'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      nome: 'seis'
    }
  ]
).toSet();

const anotherThing = Map(
  {
    id: 4,
    nome: 'quatro'
  }
);

const allThingsSorted = things
    .union(moreThings)
    .add(anotherThing)
    .sortBy(thing => thing.get('id'));

console.log(allThingsSorted); // [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
console.log(allThingsSorted.get(1)); // undefined
console.log(allThingsSorted.toList().get(1)); // {id: 6, nome: "seis"}
```

I expected the second log `undefined` to be equal to the third log `{id: 6, nome: "seis"}`.
What should I do to get the expected result, instead of converting to List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is like a shelf, where you put books besides each other. Each book is in a (sometimes randomly) sorted order and can be referenced by its position (index).
You can say "I want to read the 2nd book from the left".

A set on the other hand is a box full of assorted books. Its an chaotic storage, where books have no position/index (!). You can check the box wheter it contains a specific book, but not say where the book exactly is.
The key of a book in a Set is the book itself! You can only call `get` on it when you have a reference to the book already, making the method completly useless.

This concept is valid for Set in general, not just immutable. The [JavaScript native Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) does not even have a `get`, it only has a `has` method. Immutable has all these methods on the Set because it uses the Collection interface on all collection types. 
**Not all of these methods make sense.**  Furthermore, the description in the docs might be misleading sometimes, as it often is derived from the parent class.

Sets are useful when you only need to check wheter your list contains an object or not. Lists on the other hand are for when you need an ordered collection and need to be able to get an object by it's index.
The collection types of Immutable can be easily converted to an other collection type. You already figured this out, as you merged a Set with a List. Note that `allThingsSorted = things.union(moreThings)` results in a Set, as the object on which you call `union` defines the type.

If you need to have indexes on a Set, use [OrderedSet](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedSet)! You can call `toIndexedSeq()` on it to get an iterable list, where you can `get` by index

Comment: This might sound like set's are not cool - that's not true. Set's are usually much faster than Lists at checking wheter it contains an item.

Answer (score 2):

`List.get` get's an element by its index in the list, so `.get(1)` returns the second element (which is the one with id:6 after sorting).

`Set.get` will get an element by its id, so `.get(1)` looks for an element with id:1 which it doesn't find

Comment: Hi @Adam.Er8 . Is this `id` the one that i've defined inside the Map? Because if I try to `console.log(allThingsSorted.get(6))` it returns undefined again

Comment: Oh, sorry, the elements in your set are Maps! so `.get()` will only work if you depict the actual map you want to get.

Comment: What do you mean by depict? Convert the Maps to JS Objects?

Comment: Set is just a collection of values, no keys, so `.get` expects to get a value that is in the set (it like asking `.has` and getting the value if `.has` is true): https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set/get

Comment: Sorry, can you show me an example so that I can understand? (sorry for much questions but I already read the docs and tried everything in a stackblitz test project and that is not clicking in me because for me the keys are `id` and `nome` and I can't retrieve what I'm looking for, no matter if I do `get(6)` or `get(id)` or `get('id')` or `get('6')` )